# Ionic 4 text selection is not smooth

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am using basic Ionic 4 template with Text selection enabled ( [ionic 2: How to make text selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672568/ionic-2-how-to-make-text-selectable)), but the selection text is not so smooth and janky on iOS.

any idea why it's behaving so wired and any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make text selectable within an Ionic app, so you can copy and paste, I would recommend using the Ionic Native clipboard plugin.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/clipboard

Comment: the issue is being text highlight scrolling instead staying on the selection region. I have already opened this issue on Ionic portal https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17753

Comment: Do you have a sample project to demo this behavior?

Comment: its a fresh project and enable user-select as text