# Is there any way to make Ionic 4 text selectable?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want users to be able to select text content so that they can copy it and paste it elsewhere, but it seems that text selection has been disabled. Users can select text that is in an input or a textarea, but I want them to be able to select even regular content text. Is there a way to enable text selection?

I tried this solution: [ionic 2: How to make text selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672568/ionic-2-how-to-make-text-selectable/46437066#46437066). It doesn't work.

Is it possible to make Ionic 4 text selectable and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution in this post https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17753

I also know there is a clipboard management plugin but I never used it: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/clipboard